# AWS S3 Server side encryption Access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

- I have A and B AWS accounts and I am syncing S3 bucket from A account SoruceS3Bucket to B account DestinationS3Bucket.
- Following is the bucket policy which is applied on Destination bucket and it is allowing Source AWS account to sync the content with DestinationS3Bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionsToAAccount",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DestinationS3Bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::DestinationS3Bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- Here the sync was working perfectly since long time and it is still working but from last few days at the DestinationS3Bucket files are not accessible with the **Server side encryption Access denied** error.
- I have verified there no encryption(Default encryption, none) on SourceS3Bucket and DestinationS3Bucket and I am using Source AWS account secret and access key to sync the content. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you get this error, are you using credentials as the source account or the destination account? The file owner is the source account. Check the S3 ACL on a problem file.

Comment: The credentials are used from source AWS account. The error was showing in AWS S3 console at file level under "Server side encryption" as Access denied instead of None, AES-256 and AWS-KMS. The file owner was source account. Yes, The issue was with ACL. It worked with "--acl bucket-owner-full-control" flag. Thanks John :)

Comment: Thanks @Nitin. I created an answer based upon this solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you copy files from one S3 bucket in account A using credentials of account A to a bucket in account B, the owner of the files in the destination bucket will be account A. (Account A is the principal that created the files in account B's bucket).

During the file copy from source to destination bucket, add the `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` option so that account B can control the files. Otherwise you might have files in account B's bucket that account B cannot access or control.

Another option is to use the credentials of account B to copy from the source to the destination bucket. This way the owner of the copied files is account B.

Comment: That flag still does not change the owner, how can I change the owner after the bucket has been copied?

Comment: You cannot change the owner of a object in S3. You can copy the file in-place which creates a new S3 object and destroys the old object. There are side effects such as copy time, bandwidth, storage cost, metadata, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the files and the metadata together this way --

```
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket s3://yourbucket --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control --metadata-directive REPLACE
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution provided by John Hanely works, but that does not immediately change the ownership. You would need to execute a separate command to change it

First Step:

```
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket s3://yourbucket --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Second Step:

```
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket s3://yourbucket --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE
```

Notice `--meta-directive REPLACE`

Comment: This is good information but be careful with these commands as they have side effects. 1) You cannot change the owner of an S3 file. The command above does a file copy and replace which has time and cost side effects. 2) --meta-directive REPLACE will remove metatadata such as content-type which will break many things.

Comment: I spoke with the AWS support guys and they did not mention that, thanks for the info though :-)

Comment: In my use case senario I do not have complete access to the origin source account, therefore can hardly do anything. I just wanted the exact replica of the bucket and change its ownership.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cp it.

Assumptions: You have access to the offending account and that account has putobjectacl policy permissions.

Tells you who put the file and who has access:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket yourbucket --key path/to/file
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "the-account-putting-the-thing",
        "ID": "offendingaccountrandomidstringthatisntrelaventhere"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "the-account-putting-the-thing",
                "ID": "offendingaccountrandomidstringthatisntrelaventhere",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

To fix this so the destination owner now controls the file:

```
$ aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket yourbucket --key path/to/file --acl bucket-owner-full-control
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket yourbucket --key path/to/file
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "the-account-putting-the-thing",
        "ID": "offendingaccountrandomidstringthatisntrelaventhere"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "the-account-putting-the-thing",
                "ID": "offendingaccountrandomidstringthatisntrelaventhere",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "the-account-recieving-the-thing",
                "ID": "destinationaccountrandomidstringthatisntrelaventhere",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

I didn't have any issues manipulating the file after changing the acl vi s3api from the destination / owner account role.

Special thanks to the previous answerees. Without you, I wouldn't have been able to fix my mistake.