# AWS s3 access denied for second identical bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS S3 panel I have created bucket named the same as my account (eu-central-1). Using rest service, my user key and secret key, I have access to my first bucket, I send images via rest service, delete them, get them etc..

I have created second bucket (eu-central1) and chosen to take settings from the first one. Second bucket is not named as my account of course.

When I call list buckets I get 2 buckets, one is named same as my account name. This is the bucket that works.

Both of the buckets have blocked public access. So only way is to send images via rest service using signed headers.

Whatever I want to do with second bucket I get access denied.

But if i delete the second bucket and create new one in eu-easet-1 Than all works perfectly also for the second bucket.
Why cant i have 2 buckets in same region

Comment: What are the policies attached to the IAM role/user that is used to access the second bucket?

Comment: Hello. I have not attached any polices. Neither to the first bucket nor to the second. When I go to permissions and click on edit polices there is nothing beneath Policy.
Both of the buckets have block all public access

Comment: I'm not talking about the bucket policy. I was referring to the IAM policy.

Comment: Does the user whose access keys you are using have access to both buckets?  You'll need `s3:PutObject` and perhaps `s3:PutObjectAcl` permissions to the inside of the bucket: `arn:aws:s3:::yourBucketName/*`  (note the /* suffix for the `s3:PutObject` permission)

Comment: Here is an interesting finding. If i add new bucket with us-east-1 region then it works. If the second bucket is in same region it does not work

Comment: Are all the buckets named differently, or is the only one that is working named the same as your account name? Have you successfully managed to access one that is _not_ named after your account name? Are you an Admin for this AWS account, or did somebody else give you your credentials?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for reading my question. For some reason after 24 hours everything started working again. I have also posted an answer with detail region explanation.

Answer (score 1):

as @Nico mentioned in comments,
You need to have something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListObjectsInBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": [
                         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-one/*",
                         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-two/*"
                        ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllObjectActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": [
                         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-one/*",
                         "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-two/*"
                        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Reference Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you said that you are encountering problems if your buckets are in different regions.  When you integrate with S3 you must make sure your "client" is configured with the region of the S3 bucket.

For example in the Java SDK I get a `S3Client` as follows:

```
private static S3Client getClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsAuth, Region awsRegion) {
    return S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(awsAuth).region(awsRegion).build();
}
```

The `Region` method argument refers to the region in which the bucket is located.  I then integrate with S3 using this region-aware `S3Client`-object.  (It opens a connection to that AWS region)

In the comments I also mentioned IAM policies and that your access key needs the relevant access.  Seems you got that sorted - I just want to clarify one thing I thought about afterwards and it might be useful to you on your AWS journey ahead.

You need the `s3:putObject` permission.

`s3:putObjectAcl` might be for more advanced use-cases - for example (there might be other examples) copying an S3 object to another account.  Eg copying a file from an application on your primary AWS account to another where you manage data for analytics.  Some reference material [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040978/aws-server-side-encryption-access-denied-change-encryption-failure-for-root-u/51998093#51998093) with details on some headers that will need to accompany your `PutObject`-request.

Comment: So yes, the S3 bucket name is a global namespace.  But you still need to connect to the region in which the S3 bucket is actually located.

Comment: Thank you. I have also posted an answer with detail explanation. The real reason behind access denied issue was not clear to me. After 24 hours all was working correctly

Comment: @Dime  I have met the exactly same issue; I hope all will be working after 24 hours....

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me figure out S3 service in depth.

Just the note: I am using the root user. ID and secret key used in following examples are both root and later created user with full s3 privileges. Always the issue was the same.

In order to further research this problem I have created 6 buckets 24 hours before this comment.

1. bucket name like account name    EU (Frankfurt) eu-central-1
2. random working bucket name       EU (Frankfurt) eu-central-1
3. random working bucket name       EU (London) eu-west-2
4. random working bucket name       US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1
5. random working bucket name       US East (N. Virginia) us-east-1
6. random working bucket name       US East (Ohio) us-east-2

Numbers, 1,4,5,6 were working at the exact moment of creation. Numbers 2,3 were not. I was receiving access denied no meter what I tried to do with them (2 and 3).
All the buckets were created in the same way with completely same settings

After 24 hours, today.
I have tested access to all the buckets. No code alterations were done. Same code same functions, same tests. No bucket settings were changed in the admin panel of AWS S3. No new users were created. Everything was completely the same as it was 24 hours ago.

All the buckets were working today.

Comment: I see the [AWS Java SDK S3 examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html#create-bucket) now also contains a `S3Waiter` class that helps you poll S3 until your S3 bucket has been created.  The same `Waiter`-pattern might be encountered when working with DynamoDb as per the examples documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/waiters.html)

Comment: I've got a very similar problem. I'm getting Access Denied for new buckets no matter what. Did you find out why this was?

Comment: @RobertSamarji Hi Robert. I actually did not find the real solution. It just fixed itself after a day or two. Maybe the problem was that i have created a lot of buckets and afterword's I deleted them and created new ones that i tried to use. So maybe it took some time for S3 to register new buckets. But this is just a hunch. I am not sure. Sorry

Comment: God this is so painful. I have stuck with this same issue for a whole day. Now seeing your answer, I think I'll just take some sleep first...