# AWS S3: can perform PutObject on one bucket but get "Access Denied" error on another bucket with the identical configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am really pulling my hair off on this one.

I tried to run this command on my EC2 instance:

```
aws s3 cp test123.txt s3://lambda-layer-myapp/test123.txt
```

and got the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I just created this bucket `lambda-layer-myapp` today (within 24 hours)

This bucket has the exactly same configurations on everything with a previously created bucket named `myTestBucket`: Same region, same permissions, same everything.

The only difference is the name and time of creation.

IN the EC2 instance, I tried to run:

```
aws s3 cp test123.txt s3://myTestBucket/test123.txt
```

and BOOM! It works! Successful!

I have configure AWS permissions such that:

1. the IAM role that my EC2 instance is using has full S3 access to all resources;
2. the IAM role that my EC2 instance is using has full KMS access to all resources;
3. the bucket `lambda-layer-myapp` and the bucket `myTestBucket` are identical;

What could be causing the "PutObject operation: Access Denied" error on the newly created bucket ????

I found this relevant question: [AWS s3 access denied for second identical bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66732751/aws-s3-access-denied-for-second-identical-bucket)

and the poster said:

> The real reason behind access denied issue was not clear to me. After
> 24 hours all was working correctly

Do we have to wait for 24 hours for S3 buckets to work?

Comment: No, you don't have to wait 24 hours. It's typically immediate, or within a few seconds in my experience, at least for buckets in us-east-1. If you use the AWS Console, do you see this new bucket and can you upload to this new bucket? Did a same-named bucket exist previously and you deleted it, then re-created it?

Comment: @jarmod I do see this new bucket and I cannot upload to this new bucket because I see this error " PutObject operation: Access Denied". and No, a same-named bucket does NOT exist  previously.  I am having a really bad headache now.

Comment: What S3 permissions do you have when accessing the S3 console? What bucket policy, if any, does the S3 bucket have? Add them to your question, preferably.

Comment: did you try to perform any other actions like get object list? was it working?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to find the reason: a VPC Endpoint was limiting access from the VPC.

Here is what I did one day earlier to when I got stuck with the above issue:

1. I needed to deploy an AWS Lambda function with access to an EFS file system in my VPC. Therefore I had to deployed the AWS Lambda function with VPC configuration.
2. This Lambda function is supposed to download files from S3 bucket into the EFS file system, do some work and upload files from EFS back to S3 bucket. In order for the Lambda function in the VPC to access S3 bucket, I had to add a VPC Endpoint for S3 in my VPC dashboard.
3. I configure the permission policy of the VPC Endpoint as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123123123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123123123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myTestBucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myTestBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and `myTestBucket` is the bucket that contains the files needed to be downloaded, processed and re-uploaded again.

Therefore, I have created a situation where everything in my VPC can only perform 3 types of actions on that bucket only.

As soon as I configured the VPC Endpoint to allowed full access:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything worked just fine.